Finite Boolean combinations of rational intervals, as a subspace of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$: is it $C^*$-embedded?
Setup: Consider $X = \lbrace 0,1\rbrace ^{\mathbb{R}}$ with the product topology, which we might freely identify with the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$ through characteristic functions.
Let $D \subseteq X$ be the subset consisting of characteristic functions of finite Boolean combinations of intervals with rational endpoints.  (I don't expect that the exact definition matters much, but in case it does: an “interval” here is allowed to be open, closed or half-open, and can even be a singleton or a half-line or the full real line.  Equivalently, $D$ consists of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ which are continuous — i.e., constant — outside of at most finitely many rationals.)
We give $D$ the topology it inherits as a subspace of $X$.  Note that $D$ is countable, and that it is dense in $X$ (it is dense because any finite set of conditions of the form $h(x)=0$ or $h(x)=1$ for finitely many $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is satisfied by an element of $D$).  For what it's worth, one might also note that $D$ embeds in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace ^{\mathbb{Q}}$, and, as such, it is metrizable and, in fact, ultrametrizable. [Correction (2024-09-07): while it is true that $D$ can be seen as a subset of $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace ^{\mathbb{Q}}$, the induced topology is not the same.]
THE QUESTION: which of the following conditions, in which we have (1)⇔(2)⇔(3) ⇒ (4)⇔(5), are in fact true?

Any bounded continuous function $D\to\mathbb{R}$ extends (obviously uniquely) to all of $X$.

The Stone-Čech map $\beta D \to X$ associated to the subspace inclusion $D \to X$ is a homeomorphism.

The Stone-Čech map $\beta D \to X$ associated to the subspace inclusion $D \to X$ is injective.

The Boolean algebra $\operatorname{Clop}(D)$ of clopen subsets of $D$ is the free Boolean algebra generated by $(e_x)_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$, where $e_x$ is associated with the clopen subset $\lbrace h\in D : h(x)=1\rbrace$ of $D$.

Every clopen subset of $D$ is a finite Boolean combination of those of the form $\lbrace h\in D : h(x)=1\rbrace$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.


[Correction (2024-09-07): I had initially written the question thinking they were all equivalent (and indeed I would be surprised if it turned out that (4)/(5) are true but (1)/(2)/(3) are not), but my proof of (4)⇒(2) rested on the assertion that $D$ is strongly zero-dimensional, for which my proof was flawed, so I must correct this.]
Proof of the equivalences: The equivalence (1)⇔(2) follows from Gillman & Jerison, Rings of Continuous Functions, theorem 6.5(II).  That (2)⇒(3) is trivial, and that (3)⇒(2) follows from the fact that $\beta D \to X$ is surjective (its image is closed because $\beta D$ is compact, and dense because $D$ is dense) and that a continuous bijection between compact spaces is a homeomorphism.
To see that (2)⇒(4), note that $X$ is the Stone space of the free Boolean algebra over $(e_x)_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$; and $\beta D$ is a compact subset of $X$, so it is a Stone space as well; so now we can apply Stone duality for Boolean algebras.  Also note that $\operatorname{Clop}(D) = \operatorname{Clop}(\beta D)$ (this is the set of idempotents of the ring $C ^ *(D) = C ^ *(\beta D)$ of bounded continuous functions on $D$).  Stone duality tells us that $\beta D \to X$ is an isomorphism iff $\operatorname{Clop}(X) \to \operatorname{Clop}(D)$ is one, which gives the implication (2)⇒(4).  Finally, (5) tells us that $\operatorname{Clop}(X) \to \operatorname{Clop}(D)$ is surjective, and it is injective since $D$ is dense in $X$, so in fact (5)⇔(4). ∎
Motivation of the question: a standard proof of the fact that $\operatorname{card}(\beta\mathbb{N}) = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ goes as follows.  That $\operatorname{card}(\beta\mathbb{N}) \leq 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ is easy, so the point is to prove that $\operatorname{card}(\beta\mathbb{N}) \geq 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.  For this, it is enough to construct a surjection $\beta\mathbb{N} \to X$ (where $X = \lbrace 0,1\rbrace ^{\mathbb{R}}$ is as above); but since $D$ is countable, we have a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to D$ which composed with the inclusion $D \to X$ gives a map $\mathbb{N} \to X$ whose associated Stone-Čech map $\beta\mathbb{N} \to X$ is surjective (for the same reason as in the proof above: the image is closed and dense). ∎  ❧ Now this proof involves the maps $\beta\mathbb{N} \to \beta D \to X$, both of which are surjective, and it is a natural question in this context to wonder whether the second is in fact a homeomorphism, which is what I ask here.
Given the above equivalences I feel like this should be a fairly straightforward matter to decide, but I only managed to find myself turning in circles, so I suspect I must have missed something obvious.

I don't get why your “obviously uniquely” is obvious :-(

@JeanAbouSamra $D$ is dense in $X$.

@DavidGao Ah yes, thanks.

This is a cool construction, thinking about it is very fun! I'm curious, do you have any examples of continuous functions from $X$ (or $D$) to $\mathbb{R}$ with infinite image? I'm having trouble coming up with any.

@MartianInvader Pick any sequence $(x_n)$ of distinct reals, and consider the function taking $h\in X$ to $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 2^{-n-1} h(x_n)$. Its image on $X$ is $[0,1]$ (and its image on $D$ is the set of dyadics in $[0,1]$).

Thanks! I see how it works now. It seems to me that one could attempt to prove (5) directly from the definition of the product topology (explicitly characterizing open and closed sets in $X$ and therefore $D$), is there a complication I'm not seeing that makes this difficult?

@MartianInvader While it is true by definition that if $D$ is a subspace of $X$, every open set of $D$ is the intersection with $D$ of an open set of $X$, and ditto for “closed”, this generally does not hold for “clopen” as the example of $D=\mathbb{Q}$ inside $X=\mathbb{R}$ shows. Equivalently, a continuous function $D\to{0,1}$ does not necessarily extend to a continuous function $X\to{0,1}$ (this is quite analogous to the notion of being $C^*$-embedded which is the same statement for functions $\to\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\to{0,1}$).

The approach I was suggesting was getting to an explicit characterization of "open in $D$" first, then using that to characterize "clopen in $D$". In particular, it seems at a high level one could take the steps 1) Prove that open sets in $X$ are exactly "unions of finite intersections of sets that take a given value on a given point", 2) Prove that open sets in $D$ are exactly "unions of finite intersections of sets that take a given value on a given point", 3) Use the previous step to characterize clopen sets of $D$, and finally prove your statement (5). But I haven't tried the details.

@MartianInvader I just posted a self-answer showing that (5) (and hence all the other statements) is, in fact, false.

I read through your answer and left a couple comments, but isn't it showing that (1) is false, not (5)?

@MartianInvader The answer shows that not every continuous function $D\to{0,1}$ extends to a continuous $X\to{0,1}$. This is the same as saying that not every clopen subset of $D$ is the intersection with $D$ of a clopen subset of $X$. And since clopen subsets of $X$ are finite Boolean combination of those of the form ${h : h(x)=1}$, this is the same as (5). Yes, maybe these should have been statements (6) and (7) or something, both equivalent to (5).

(I asked a related question on MathOverflow, to which I recieved an answer by KP Hart with references to a paper by Engelking and Pełczyński which is used as inspiration in the following direct answer to my own question.)
I claim that all statements (1)–(5) in the question are false: by the implications proved in the question itself, it is enough to show that (5) is false.  I will do this by constructing a (fairly explicit) continuous function $F: D \to \{0,1\}$ which does not extend to a continuous function $X \to \{0,1\}$ (recall that clopen subsets of a topological space and continuous functions to $\{0,1\}$ can be identified by means of the characteristic function).
To do this, we will only use the fact that $D$ is countable and dense in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$ (and $\mathbb{R}$ itself can be replaced by an arbitrary infinite set).
We first construct a partition of $D$ into countably many nonempty clopen sets as follows:
Since $D$ is countable, let us enumerate its elements into a sequence $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.  Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an arbitrary sequence of pairwise distinct real numbers, and let $v_n = h_n(x_n) \in \{0,1\}$.  Inductively define a sequence of pairwise disjoint nonempty clopen subsets $C_n$ of $D$ by:
$$
C_n \;:=\; \{h \in D : h(x_n) = v_n\} \,\setminus\, \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1} C_i
$$
Note that $\{h \in D : h(x_n) = v_n\} \subseteq D$ is clopen by definition of the product topology, so $C_n$ is clopen.  That the $C_n$ are pairwise disjoint is obvious by construction.  Furthermore, $C_n$ is nonempty because, as pointed out in the question, $D$ is dense in the sense that for any $n$ we can find $h$ such that $h(x_i) = 1-v_i$ for $i<n$ and $h(x_n) = v_n$, which ensures $h \in C_n$.
Finally, since $h_n \in \bigcup_{i=0}^n C_i$ by definition of $v_n$, we have $\bigcup_{i=0}^{+\infty} C_i = D$.  So the $C_n$ are indeed a partition of $D$ into countably many nonempty clopen sets.
Now define the function $F\colon D \to \{0,1\}$ as follows: if $h \in C_i$, we let $F(h) = 0$ when $i$ is even or $F(h) = 1$ when $i$ is odd.  This function is defined on all of $D$ by what has just been said, and it is continuous (viꝫ. locally constant) because the $C_i$ are open.
I now claim that $F$ does not extend to a continuous function on $X$ with values in $\{0,1\}$ (or indeed even not even in $\mathbb{R}$, as $F^2 = F$ on $D$ implies that any real-valued extension to $X$ would satisfy the same and thus take values in $\{0,1\}$).
To show this, assume by contradiction that $\widehat{F} \colon X \to \{0,1\}$ is such an extension.
As pointed out in the question, $X$ is the Stone space of the free Boolean algebra on $e_x$ (identified with $h \mapsto h(x)$) for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so by Stone duality any clopen subset of $X$ is a finite Boolean combination of the $\{h\in X : h(x)=1\}$.  This means that $\widehat{F}(h)$ can depend only on finitely many values $h(y_1),\ldots,h(y_m)$ of $h$ (in the sense that if $h,h'$ take the same values at $y_1,\ldots,y_m$, then $\widehat{F}(h)=\widehat{F}(h')$).
Let $n$ be such that $x_i \not\in \{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$ if $i\geq n$.  As explained above, by density of $D$ we can find $h$ such that $h(x_i) = 1-v_i$ for $i<n$ and $h(x_n) = v_n$ (where $(x_n)$ and $(v_n)$ are as constructed above).  Let $w_j = h(y_j)$ for $1\leq j\leq m$.  Again by density of $D$ we can find $h'$ such that $h'(x_i) = 1-v_i$ for $i<n$ and $h'(y_j) = w_j$ (note that if there is a value common to the $x_i$ and the $y_j$, these conditions are compatible because it is the value of $h$ there) and, this time, $h'(x_n) = 1-v_n$ and $h'(x_{n+1}) = v_{n+1}$.
The conditions we have given imply that $h \in C_n$ and $h' \in C_{n+1}$, so $F(h) \neq F(h')$.  But since $h$ and $h'$ take the same values $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ on $y_1,\ldots,y_m$, we have $\widehat{F}(h)=\widehat{F}(h')$, contradicting the assumption that $\widehat{F}$ extends $F$. ∎

Can you elaborate on why $\hat{F}$ can only depend on finitely many values of $h$? I don't see how it follows from any clopen subset of $X$ being a finite boolean combination - what property of $F$ are you using here?

Separate question from above - what does "$F^2 = F$" mean here? The domain and codomain of $F$ are quite different, so I don't think you mean function composition?

@MartianInvader Re 1st question: I'm only using the fact that $\hat F: X\to{0,1}$ is continuous (=locally constant). This means it is the characteristic function of a clopen subset $C\subseteq X$, which is a Boolean combination of finitely many ${h\in X : h(y_i)=1}$, which easily implies that $\hat F(h)$ only depends on the values $h(y_i)$ (if you prefer: “the truth value $\hat F(h)$ of $h\in C$ only depends on the finitely many truth values $h(y_i)=1$”).

@MartianInvader Re 2d question: $F^2=F$ means that, if we see $F$ as a continuous real-valued function, it satisfies this equation (i.e., it is idempotent). Here $F^2$ is not composition, it is real multiplication: I'm just saying that the real solutions of $v^2=v$ are ${0,1}$. (This is just a digression, anyway, showing that we can't even extend $F$ as a real-valued continuous function because the extension will automatically have values in ${0,1}$. The remark was already made in the proof of (2)⇒(4) in the question: clopen subsets of $D$ can be identified with idempotents of $C^*(D)$.)

Thank you for answering all my questions, I believe I understand the proof now. One final question: Why bother extending $F$ to $X$ at all? Doesn't the construction in the last two paragraphs directly show that the (clopen) inverse images of ${0}$ and ${1}$ in $D$ cannot depend on only finitely many values, proving (5) is false?

@MartianInvader Yeah, I guess so. It's just that I prefer to think of (5) as asserting the surjectivity of the map $\operatorname{Clop}(X)\to\operatorname{Clop}(D)$ just like (1) asserts the surjectivity of $C^(X)\to C^(D)$: at any rate, if we're mostly interested in (1)-(2)-(3), at some point some argument about extending the map is bound to come up.
